# SQL or AREL query by method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

In rails, if I want to search a column in table, I just need to do a `where` search, and I can get the result quickly. for example:

```
openings = Opening.joins(:opening_number).where('opening_numbers.value = ?', value)
```

However, now I need to search by method. For instance, here is a method in `OpeningNumber` model:

```
def to_s
  value || sprintf("%03d", id % 1000)
end
```

Then I want to search by the result of this method. I don't know how to do it via `sql` or `arel`. What I can do is:

```
openings = Opening.includes(:opening_number)
  .select { |opening| opening.opening_number.to_s == value }
```

However, it is much slower than sql query and it causes the performance issue.

Does anyone know how to do it by sql or arel? Or if not, how to improve the performance like sql query?

In the past, it uses `ferrets` and mysql so it can be indexed and search. But recently we transfered mysql to postgresql and remove `ferrets`.

Comment: What is `print_using` method?

Comment: Just found the `print_using` is the custom method, updated.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically asking how to implement `value || (id % 1000).print_using("%03d")` logic in sql where statement?

Straight forward approach would be:

```
Opening.includes(:opening_number).where("opening_numbers.value = ? OR (format('%03d', (opening_numbers.id % 1000)::string))::integer = ?", value).references(:opening_numbers)
```

Also check if you still need to use `includes`. Just for this case `joins` would be enough

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it's not the answer for my question, it solved my problem specifically. There are some errors in your answer and when you fixed those I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Firstly, the `postgresql` don't have `string` data types, instead you can use `char`, `varchar` or `text`. [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE)

Comment: Secondly, `format` method don't support `d`. You should use other way to format, like `lpad`. [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)